# How to specify a dependency that does not appear in the published artifact?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a build that contains two modules `a` and `b`. `b` depends on `a`. `a` contains only resources (think: logging configuration). Locally, if I run the sbt task `b/console`, I want `a` to be on the classpath. However, I don't want to publish `a` and hence don't want the dependency to appear in `b`'s artifact. How can I configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'provided' scope when adding the library dependency

```
libraryDependencies += "javax.servlet" % "javax.servlet-api" % "3.0.1" % "provided"
```